# UITextField delegate

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a `UITextFiled` to which I applied the delegate to close the keyboard by pressing "done".

```
    ...
    textfield.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    textfield.delegate = self;
    ....

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {

    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

How do I invoke a method when I press "done"?

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, this is not related to Xcode. Retagging.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is it that what you want ?

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    [add your method here];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When the "done" button is pressed, your editing on the field will end. You can call the delegate method:

```
textFieldDidEndEditing:
```

This method is called when the field resigns its first responder status, so it will be called also when you execute your `textFieldShouldReturn` like you specified it.

Answer (score 2):

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Text Field Delegate
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    if ([textField canResignFirstResponder]) {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
    }

    return YES;
}
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    // add your method here

    return YES;
}
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

}
```

Comment: try to improve your answer, you just put a piece of code without explaining how it would help the original poster.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    [add your method here];
    return YES;
}
```